# JSF Ajax Response populating input fields for form submit

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, facelets

I'm parsing some data in a java file for which I'm passing parameters through ajax to the method and it parses the data and returns them in an object - in a model bean. Then I can display this value in JSF 2 with

```
<h2><h:outputText id="output1" value="#{model.method.price}" /></h2>
```

This works.

Ok but I want to output all of these values inside their correspondent inputText fields. Then I'd like to edit them and submit them to the form...
But this is tricky. As for outputting the text is done with value and so is for inputing it.

For an form "value" is used - as also the output in the ajax response. What to do?

I want to do something like :

```
<h:outputLabel value="Evaluate if price is ok:" />
<h:inputText value="#{model.method.price}" value_submit="#{evaluate.price}" />
<br/>
 <p><h:commandButton value="Vnos" action="evaluate.submit"/></p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just directly access the property behind `#{model.method.price}` inside `submit()` method?

Comment: I have a couple of input fields to fill out. All preformatted with a ajax value output. method.price ; method.name ; method.xy